# How to get a PerSession context with WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I got running a WCF service with custom binding, for now it use httpTransport.

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="myHttpBindingConf">
        <context contextManagementEnabled="true" protectionLevel="None"
                    contextExchangeMechanism="ContextSoapHeader" />
        <textMessageEncoding/>
        <httpTransport useDefaultWebProxy="false" />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

I've Made a custom `IExtension<OperationContext>` to stock my data in a specific context by following those instructions:
http://hyperthink.net/blog/a-simple-ish-approach-to-custom-context-in-wcf/

I would like to use a `ContextMode.PerSession` context.

Which transport choose to get Session management?
How to set new transport in place and letting object discovery enabled?
How to force a PerSession context?

Comment: I've made it running well with wshttpbinding.
if you are in the same trouble, you may look at my Web.config here:


http://code.google.com/p/tte-knbc/source/browse/trunk/BusinessLayer/Web.config

you may downlowd the whole project under therms of CECIL-L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to establish a session does not necessarily depend only the used transport. E.g. you can use  WS-SecureConversion to establish a session and still use HTTP(s) transport.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx section "System-Provided Session Types".

Also you would usually tie your service instance to a session, not the operation context.

Answer (score 0):

You specify it in the implementation of your service rather than in a config file

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class MyService : IMyService
```

Comment: in fact, I don't know how to handle this in my custom behavior made in C# as described in the tutorial...